# Помогите получить значение

Tags: python

Поток веб сокетов постоянно обновляется, вместе с ним мне нужно вывести значение price, которое будет под значением "c". Помогите вывести

socket = f'wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/adausdt@ticker'
ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(socket, on_message=on_message, on_close=on_close)

**price =**

ws.run_forever()

> {"e":"24hrTicker","E":1664645192506,"s":"ADAUSDT","p":"-0.00650000","P":"-1.495","w":"0.43239690","x":"0.43480000","c":"0.42840000","Q":"7115.40000000","b":"0.42830000","B":"39380.30000000","a":"0.42840000","A":"10065.80000000","o":"0.43490000","h":"0.43680000","l":"0.42750000","v":"80667512.40000000","q":"34880382.08446000","O":1664558792490,"C":1664645192490,"F":410592894,"L":410658264,"n":65371}
> {"e":"24hrTicker","E":1664645193512,"s":"ADAUSDT","p":"-0.00650000","P":"-1.495","w":"0.43239690","x":"0.43480000","c":"0.42840000","Q":"7115.40000000","b":"0.42830000","B":"47813.10000000","a":"0.42840000","A":"10198.90000000","o":"0.43490000","h":"0.43680000","l":"0.42750000","v":"80667512.40000000","q":"34880382.08446000","O":1664558793063,"C":1664645193063,"F":410592894,"L":410658264,"n":65371}
> {"e":"24hrTicker","E":1664645194516,"s":"ADAUSDT","p":"-0.00650000","P":"-1.495","w":"0.43239688","x":"0.43490000","c":"0.42840000","Q":"7115.40000000","b":"0.42830000","B":"53972.30000000","a":"0.42840000","A":"4514.00000000","o":"0.43490000","h":"0.43680000","l":"0.42750000","v":"80666817.30000000","q":"34880079.78547000","O":1664558794398,"C":1664645194398,"F":410592895,"L":410658264,"n":65370}
> {"e":"24hrTicker","E":1664645195504,"s":"ADAUSDT","p":"-0.00640000","P":"-1.472","w":"0.43239687","x":"0.43490000","c":"0.42840000","Q":"7115.40000000","b":"0.42830000","B":"53972.30000000","a":"0.42840000","A":"548.90000000","o":"0.43480000","h":"0.43680000","l":"0.42750000","v":"80666789.30000000","q":"34880067.60827000","O":1664558794592,"C":1664645194592,"F":410592896,"L":410658264,"n":65369}
>
> *

Comment: ну так и тяните значение по ключу `c`

Answer (score 1):

```
import json

txt = '''{"e":"24hrTicker","E":1664645192506,"s":"ADAUSDT","p":"-0.00650000","P":"-1.495","w":"0.43239690",
"x":"0.43480000","c":"0.42840000","Q":"7115.40000000","b":"0.42830000","B":"39380.30000000","a":"0.42840000",
"A":"10065.80000000","o":"0.43490000","h":"0.43680000","l":"0.42750000","v":"80667512.40000000",
"q":"34880382.08446000","O":1664558792490,"C":1664645192490,"F":410592894,"L":410658264,"n":65371} '''

print(json.loads(txt)['c'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Все очень просто, вам нужно написать эту линию кода

```
price = **имя перемены**['с']
```

Comment: наверно, строку, а не линию?

Comment: да, плохой переводчик